# Difference between terminology and nomenclature?

Tags: differences, synonyms

What is the difference between terminology and nomenclature?

If I want to say that I use the same words with the exact same meaning as author X, what would you say?

- "We use the same *terminology* as author X"

or

- "We use the same *nomenclature* as author X"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see very little difference between the two:

> **terminology** |ˌtərməˈnäləjē|
>   *noun ( pl. -gies)*
>   the body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, theory, profession, etc. : *the terminology of semiotics* | *specialized terminologies for higher education.*
>
> **nomenclature** |ˈnōmənˌklā ch ər|
>   *noun*
>   the devising or choosing of names for things, esp. in a science or other discipline.
>   • the body or system of such names in a particular field : *the nomenclature of chemical compounds.*
>   • *formal* the term or terms applied to someone or something : *“customers” was preferred to the original nomenclature “passengers.”*

Based on these definitions from NOAD, *terminology* seems a little broader, that is all, while *nomenclature* seems more systematic and deliberate.

Comment: Can't downvote, but I would because the cited definitions clearly show that the two terms are distinct in meaning (as [@WillMadden's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/526947/253250) points this out beautifully), and the final editorializing is only to mislead readers

Answer (score 3):

Terminology is the specific names used in a particular field, while nomenclature is the system or method for devising new names.

E.g. in chemistry [names for compounds are derived from the structure of the compound](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/naming-compounds/). The *nomenclature* determines the way the names are formed, whereas terms like "compound", "exothermic" and "reaction" are part of the terminology of chemistry.

Having said that, both words are frequently (if incorrectly) used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference in meaning between the two example sentences but the two words have some different uses, for example, *nomenclature* can also refer to a single term or name and *terminology* can also mean 'nomenclature as a field of study'.